# Baseline in TikZ default unit of length

Tags: tikz-pgf, baseline, unit-of-measure

Lately, I have been using the *baseline* argument in TikZ pictures, but I couldn't figure out what was the default unit of length. I know that the cm is the default unit for TikZ package, but it doesn't seem to be se case for *baseline* :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

without baseline :
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45]
        \clip(-1,-1) rectangle (5,5);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (0,4)-- (4,4);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (4,4)-- (4,0);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (4,0)-- (0,0);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (0,0)-- (0,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
with baseline (no unit) :
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=2, line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45]
        \clip(-1,-1) rectangle (5,5);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (0,4)-- (4,4);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (4,4)-- (4,0);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (4,0)-- (0,0);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (0,0)-- (0,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
with baseline (cm) :
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=2cm, line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45]
        \clip(-1,-1) rectangle (5,5);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (0,4)-- (4,4);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (4,4)-- (4,0);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (4,0)-- (0,0);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (0,0)-- (0,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Does any one have any idea about where I could find this kind of information.

Best regards

Comment: Coordinates may default to 1cm (see \pgfsetxvec and \pgfsetyvec), but arguments default to pt, same as normal LaTeX (except without the error message).

Comment: Yes, this is perhaps one of the most confusing aspects of Ti*k*Z/pgf. It also expects the arguments of `sin` and `cos` to be in degrees whereas the arguments of `sinh` and `cosh` are not.

Comment: @marmot but `sinh` and `cosh` are not really trigonometric function unlike `sin` and `cos`. For the former an argument of degree seems really odd.

Comment: @Skillmon No, I certainly wouldn't want any function to have arguments in degrees.

Comment: @marmot me neither, but it is at least reasonable that `sinh` and `cosh` don't take their arguments in degrees while it is somewhat understandable that `sin` and `cos` do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this is interpreted in `pt`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

without baseline :
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45]
        \clip(-1,-1) rectangle (5,5);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (0,4)-- (4,4);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (4,4)-- (4,0);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (4,0)-- (0,0);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (0,0)-- (0,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
with baseline (no unit) :
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=2, line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45]
        \clip(-1,-1) rectangle (5,5);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (0,4)-- (4,4);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (4,4)-- (4,0);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (4,0)-- (0,0);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (0,0)-- (0,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
with baseline (pt) :
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=2pt, line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45]
        \clip(-1,-1) rectangle (5,5);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (0,4)-- (4,4);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (4,4)-- (4,0);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (4,0)-- (0,0);
        \draw [line width=1pt] (0,0)-- (0,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives identic results.

Comment: I also noticed that. But couldn't find anything to confirm it.

Comment: @IdoDaisuke I think it is not mentioned in the pgfmanual. At least not on the first 128 pages...

Comment: @IdoDaisuke page 132 mentions something related, I guess: If two numbers, one with a dimension and one without, are summed up, the dimensionless is considered pt.

Comment: @IdoDaisuke the only other information about interpreting something as pt I found is: "The dimensionless units of SVG are always interpreted as points (pt)." on page 744.